# Программы без файлов .exe

Tags: exe

Подскажите, плиз, как пользоваться программами [такого типа](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/gettext-0.20.1.tar.gz)? Файлов .exe нет, папок bin - нет. Непонятно, ни каким файлом запущать, ни какую папку добавлять в патч. Уже несколько таких прогр попадалось. Геогебра такая попалась, по-моему, один из последних релизов. Не могут же так часто попадаться левые программы.

Comment: это исходники, их нужно собрать под конкретную ОС

Comment: А мне это под силу?

Comment: @Grek79 там должна быть инструкция по сборке.

Comment: обычно все проходит гладко, если стоят необходимые пакеты, от которых зависит программа

Comment: Собственно, в файлах INSTALL и INSTALL.windows там всё написано

Comment: Есть ярлыки, есть обьекты clsid (Мой компьютер и корзина), есть другие методы передачи ссылки на исполнимый код. Нужно привести конкретные примеры программ, которые прячут исполнимый код - тогда получите более приемлемый ответ.

Comment: @nick_n_a так вон же ссылка на пример в вопросе есть

Comment: А вот интересно, почему у файла INSTALL нет расширения? Ведь там один текст. Сам Бог велел ему быть файлом .txt.

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите, плиз, как пользоваться программами такого типа?

Это исходники. Надо либо их скомпилировать, либо просто внимательно смотреть сайт:

> Michele Locati kindly provides [precompiled binaries for Windows](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html) on his site.